# forEach function not running in tcp event

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, foreach, tcp

I am trying to use the forEach() function in the node js net library in my tcp event but it is completely failing to run what is going wrong

I have made a async function to replace forEach() but it still wont work even tho i know the function is being called

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  console.log('async function')
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

nothing happens except the expected console.logs this is how i am using the function

```
sock.on('data',function(data){
  var data = Buffer.from(data).toString();
  var arg = data.split(',');
  var event = arg[0];

  if(event == 'stdout'){
    console.log('stdout')
    asyncForEach(controlClients, async (num) => {
      await waitFor(50);
      console.log(num);
    });
  }
});
```

i am expecting the return each row of the array here so i can do something for a selected controlClient any help?

Comment: What is `waitFor()`?  Please show that code.

Comment: i am actually not sure i got the code from here https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

Comment: You say "nothing happens except the expected console.logs()", but that's all the code does (output to logs).  So, I don't know what else you're expecting or what you're asking.  FYI, the code for `waitFor()` is right there in your link.  It's just a promise-based delay.

Comment: sorry for not specifying but the only console.log i get is stdout and thank you for the pointer i didnt see that code in the example must have overlooked it :)

Comment: Well, if you don't have the `waitFor()` code in what you're trying to run, that would cause an exception which would turn into an async function rejection which you aren't handling or logging.

Comment: i added the function with no changes in the output

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to figure out exactly what your full environment is.  When I run this code:

```
const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  console.log('async function')
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}

let controlClients = [1,2,3,4];

function test() {
    console.log('stdout')
    return asyncForEach(controlClients, async (num) => {
      await waitFor(50);
      console.log(num);
    });
}

test().then(() => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I get this output:

```
stdout
async function
1
2
3
4
done
```

Hopefully you can take this as a starting point and figure out what is going wrong in your particular environment.  Note, you should always have a `.catch()` on pretty much any operation that involves a promise so you can see if there are any errors in your promise chain.

And, since you don't show your socket code so I can't reproduce that part of it, I simplified to just run the rest of the code once in a small test app.